# How to call python global command inside Procedure of another file

Tags: python, html

In this below script 'a' is globally set as TC-01 and b is globally set as 'Passed' but on executing i can able to get the value of **'a'** but **'b'** value i cannot able to get , so please provide me the valuable ideas to get the value of 'b' too.

```
import HTML
import html2 
from html2 import a,b

file = open('out.html', 'w') 
# dictionary of test results, indexed by test id:
 test_results = {
a: 'b',-----> In this only a value is take , b is not taking the value.
#'Testcase-005': 'success'
#'Testcase-005': 'error',
    }

result_colors = {
'passed':      'lime',
'failed':      'red',
'error':        'yellow',
    }
t = HTML.Table(header_row=['Testcase - ID', 'Result'])
for test_id in sorted(test_results):
#create the colored cell:
print test_results
color = result_colors[test_results[test_id]]
colored_result = HTML.TableCell(test_results[test_id], bgcolor=color)
#append the row with two cells:
t.rows.append([test_id, colored_result])
htmlcode = str(t)
c=htmlcode
print htmlcode
file.write(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import HTML
import html2 
from html2 import *
#print a
#print b
file = open('out.html', 'w') 
table_data = [
['S.No',   'Testcase - ID',   'Result'],
['1',       a,         b],
['2',       c,         d],

]
htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)
c=htmlcode
print htmlcode
```

file.write(c)
after this globally call a,b,c,d...i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I think your problem is because you are setting `test_results[a]` to `'b'` instead of `b`.

That is, you're not using the value of `b`, but the string `'b'` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But here i already set two variables  a and b in (html2 file) as global, but i called in main file i cannot able to get the value of b.